# Bundle.putParcelable(String key, Parcelable value) and Intent.putExtra(String name, Parcelable value) Difference

Tags: android

I have an object that implements Parcelable interface.

**Case 1:**

I have an Activity A and B. I would like to pass object from A to B using `Intent.putExtra(String name, Parcelable value)` so in Activity B when I get object and change some fields and get back to A the field of object remain the same. That mean after pass object via `Intent.putExtra(String name, Parcelable value)` a new instance of object will be created.

**Case 2:**

I have an Activity that contains a list of objects, also that activity has ViewPager with fragments. I create fragments and pass to it object `Bundle.putParcelable(String key, Parcelable value)` so when I get object and change some fields (int Fragment) the object that place in a list(in Activity) also changed. So that mean object hasn't been created just reference has been passed to fragment.

Can someone explain that strange behavior about `Bundle.putParcelable(String key, Parcelable value)` and `Intent.putExtra(String name, Parcelable value)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `Intent` mechanism and the `set/getArguments()` of `Fragment` works differently.

When `Activity` contains `Fragment` it has direct reference to the `Fragment`, and setting a bundle on `Fragment` is simple set on the `Fragment` object, that's means that the Bundle object reference but the Activity is the same as the one in the `Fragment`. Actually you don't necessarily need this mechanism, as you're `Activity` probably controls the `Fragments` and knows their type, so you can just pass arguments by exposing a method on your `Fragment`. the benefit and the similarity to intent is that using provided `set/getArguments()` is retaining those arguments across fragment destroy and creation, those it uses `Bundle` and `Parcelable`, which are data that the system can stored outside your control.

But, `Intent` and `Activity` are different, `Activity` have no object reference to other `Activities`, and communicating must go through the system, and thus - unlike `Activity/Fragment` must be done with `Parcelable`/`Bundle` data that the system can serailze/deserialze.
When you sent an Intent to a different `Activity` your `Parcelable` goes through the system and get serailze/deserialze thus - you have a different Object reference in 2 differnt Activities.  this is not happening when you `setArgument` on `Fragment` as `Activity`/`Fragment` has no boundaries like different Activities.

Answer (score 0):

This difference is not about `putParcelable` vs. `putExtra`.
An Activity which accepts an Intent or a Fragment which accepts arguments should not mutate incoming data because it may be passed by reference (as an optimisation), or may be recreated from Parcel (when it's necessary).

If you want to return some data from Activity, use `startActivityForResult()` and `setResult()`. If you want to return some data from Fragment, use `getActivity()` to get a host Activity from a Fragment and communicate with it.